# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Worklight Upgrade process in a cluster environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Does Worklight supports server upgrade (e.g. apply fix pack, upgrade minor version, upgrade major version) without server downtime in cluster?

My understanding is that for server upgrade, there are some scripts being applied in the database. Moreover, there are some tasks being executed to sync between database and the file system.

Is it possible to upgrade the servers one by one, or sync it after one has been updated without any downtime? If so, could you please provide me the procedures? Thanks!

Environment Info: Worklight Consumer Edition 5.0.6.1, WAS 8.5, Oracle 11g RAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below may not be correct, depending on your upgrade scenario:

- Is it from 5.0.6.x to 5.0.6.x?
- Or from 5.0.6.x to 6.0.0.x or 6.1?
  -- If talking about 6.1 [then see this IC article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_overview.html)

---

In general: it is not yet possible to upgrade the servers in a cluster one-by-one. You will need to shut down all servers in the cluster and upgrade them all.

That said, I don't know what is your network topology... and an upgrade scenario can and will change depending on that.

It could be that you have 2 clusters of Worklight Servers, each with its own database, and a load balancer that redirects app requests:

```
[load          balancer]
   |              | 
   |              |
   |              | 
[WL cluster]   [WL cluster]
-s -s -s -s    -s -s -s -s
   |              |
  [DB]           [DB]
```

In such a case you can:

1. Direct all traffic to one cluster
2. Take down the other cluster, upgrade all servers, restart
3. Direct all traffic to the upgraded cluster
4. Take down the unupgraded cluster, upgrade all servers, restart
5. Direct again the traffic to both clusters

Comment: Thanks Idan. The topology is that we have one WL cluster, two WL servers under that cluster and share same database.
So, it seems that we must need to stop all servers under the cluster to do any kind of Worklight upgrade?

Comment: I would believe so, because there is currently no option to upgrade while the server is running.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Can I further ask how about app deployment? Can we deploy the app without downtime?

Comment: For example, Question1: If I want to deploy the WAR file, can it be deployed through WAS admin console without downtime, say updating the WAR file in one server first, and then the other? My current procedure to deploy the WAR file is: (a) Stop cluster (b) Update Enterprise Applications (WAR file) (c) Start cluster ... Question2: If I want to deploy the .wlapp and .adapter files in Worklight console, can it be deployed without downtime? Seems like while the files are uploading, the server cannot be accessible.

Comment: 1) You cannot update a war file without shutting down the server hosting it. 2) The server must be online if deploying a new artifact (adapter, app). It is true that the server will be "locked", but this is a fraction of a time, and you do not deploy new versions during production every day... so the "damage" is VERY minimal. This is something will may be addressed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The documented in place upgrade procedures (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/topics/t_upgrading.html)  include some downtime.

Issues to anticipate to minimize downtime include:
    - porting the server side artifacts (wlapp and adaptaers) to the new version and being ready to upload them (not needed in 6.1 that provides separation of studio and server lifecycle)
    - database schema update

In the 6.1 version the downtime for an in-place upgrade can be minimized to this:

1. stop servers
2. upgrade database
3. upgrade the first server and restart it.

-> If Application Center is not installed or not installed on the same application server than the worklight server.

This is summarized in the table attached to this page:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_overview.html

Comment: Thanks Didier. From [this spreadsheet](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/Worklight_Server_Upgrade_Steps.xls), there is summary for the WL server upgrade procedure. One point which I am not quite sure is some Worklight server status is "RUNNING" / "STOPPED" depends on it is liberty / tomcat. What makes the difference to these kinds of app server than the WAS full profile / ND?

Comment: For some application servers, the server must be stopped before IBM Installation Manager runs. The details are here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrade_to_srvr610_start_shutting_down_appsrvr.html.

Comment: For ideas about a zero downtime rolling upgrade for Worklight Server fix packs (no database change), this paper may give good insight http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0412_vansickel/0412_vansickel.html